# Docker client build error

Tags: go, docker

This defeats me. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. There is so less documentation that searching did not produce good result. I will be happy to see what is the reason behind this strange behaviour.

I am on a MAC (10.11.6) and I am running docker for MAC (beta)

Here is the code I am trying to run

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
)

func main() {
    defaultHeaders := map[string]string{"User-Agent": "ego-v-0.0.1"}
    cli, _ := client.NewClient("unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "v1.24", nil, defaultHeaders)
    options := types.ImageBuildOptions{
        Dockerfile:     "/path/to/my/Dockerfile",
        SuppressOutput: false,
        Remove:         true,
        ForceRemove:    true,
        PullParent:     true}
    buildResponse, err := cli.ImageBuild(context.Background(), nil, options)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", buildResponse.OSType)
}
```

This gives me this error -

```
Error response from daemon: {"message":"Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: /path/to/my/Dockerfile"}
```

Whereas when I run this command (from the same directory where my Go code is)

```
docker build /path/to/my
```

It works absolutely fine.

What am I doing wrong? I feel like banging my head against a wall now. Please help.

------------ EDIT / ADD ------------
I ended up doing this -

```
package main

import (
    "archive/tar"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/net/context"

    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
)

func tarit(source, target string) error {
    filename := filepath.Base(source)
    target = filepath.Join(target, fmt.Sprintf("%s.tar", filename))
    fmt.Println(target)
    tarfile, err := os.Create(target)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer tarfile.Close()

    tarball := tar.NewWriter(tarfile)
    defer tarball.Close()

    info, err := os.Stat(source)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }

    var baseDir string
    if info.IsDir() {
        baseDir = filepath.Base(source)
    }

    return filepath.Walk(source,
        func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            header, err := tar.FileInfoHeader(info, info.Name())
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            if baseDir != "" {
                header.Name = filepath.Join(baseDir, strings.TrimPrefix(path, source))
            }

            if err := tarball.WriteHeader(header); err != nil {
                return err
            }

            if info.IsDir() {
                return nil
            }

            file, err := os.Open(path)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            defer file.Close()
            _, err = io.Copy(tarball, file)
            return err
        })
}

func main() {
    tarit("/dir/with/files/and/dockerfile", "repo")
    dockerBuildContext, err := os.Open("./repo.tar")
    defer dockerBuildContext.Close()
    defaultHeaders := map[string]string{"User-Agent": "ego-v-0.0.1"}
    cli, _ := client.NewClient("unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "v1.24", nil, defaultHeaders)
    options := types.ImageBuildOptions{
        Dockerfile:     "repo/Dockerfile",
        SuppressOutput: false,
        Remove:         true,
        ForceRemove:    true,
        PullParent:     true}
    buildResponse, err := cli.ImageBuild(context.Background(), dockerBuildContext, options)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("********* %s **********", buildResponse.OSType)
}
```

Now it is not complaining about anything and I can see that the tar is getting made properly and the last println is printing

```
********* linux **********
```

Which is a reply from the server. But it does not build anything. I understand that reply is almost immediate as under the hood it is just a POST request. But not sure why it is not building anything although.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working code to this problem. For anyone who will probably be stuck like me -

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"

    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
    "github.com/jhoonb/archivex"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
)

func main() {
    tar := new(archivex.TarFile)
    tar.Create("/path/to/tar/archieve")
    tar.AddAll("/path/to/base/folder", false)
    tar.Close()
    dockerBuildContext, err := os.Open("/path/to/tar/archieve.tar")
    defer dockerBuildContext.Close()
    defaultHeaders := map[string]string{"Content-Type": "application/tar"}
    cli, _ := client.NewClient("unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "v1.24", nil, defaultHeaders)
    options := types.ImageBuildOptions{
        SuppressOutput: true,
        Remove:         true,
        ForceRemove:    true,
        PullParent:     true,
        Tags:           []string{"xxx"}}
    buildResponse, err := cli.ImageBuild(context.Background(), dockerBuildContext, options)
    defer buildResponse.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err.Error())
    }
    //time.Sleep(5000 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Printf("********* %s **********", buildResponse.OSType)
    response, err := ioutil.ReadAll(buildResponse.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(string(response))
}
```

Be careful that a lot of error checks are not done in this code. This is just a working code where I am using docker client lib successfully.

Let me know what you think.

Thanks to -

> "github.com/jhoonb/archivex"

Answer (score 0):

The Dockerfile has to be part of the build context that gets TARd and sent to the engine. You shouldn't use an absolute path to the Dockerfile, it [must be relative to the context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#/build-with-path), so you just pass the name.

I don't think the CLI command you demonstrate is right - unless `Dockerfile` is actually a directory name in your case:

```
> ls /tmp/path/to/context 
Dockerfile
> docker build /tmp/path/to/context/Dockerfile
unable to prepare context: context must be a directory: /tmp/path/to/context/Dockerfile
```

When you send just the path (which contains the Dockerfile file), that works:

```
> docker build /tmp/path/to/context
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM alpine
 ---> ee4603260daa
Successfully built ee4603260daa
```

Comment: There was a slight error in my post. When I am using the command from command line I am not adding the Dockerfile at the end of it. I am giving just the path to the dockerfile and the client automatically detects the Dockerfile present in that path. I expected the same to happen with the code. But it is not. So essentially what works for the default client does not work for y code. This is what is strange.

Comment: The CLI does an extra step - it TARs the context directory before sending it to the API to build. That's the step you're missing - you're sending `nil` as the context. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38804313/build-docker-image-from-go-code) which shows you how to send the build context in the Go client.

Comment: I took your suggestion and after some time of trial and error I ended up to the code I have posted under edit. Now it does not complain about anything but it is not building anything also. I am trying to look into this. Problem is, there is absolutely no documentation on this that I can find. So strange!

Comment: I posted an answer that worked for me. Please check it.